# set toolbar on each fragments in viewpager

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

**How to set toolbar on every fragment of viewpager? There is a single fragment with multiple instaces in viewpager have seprate toolbar.**

I am stuck in this problem last two days.
Please give me your valuable feedback's.so that i can move forward.